# Validate empty value for dynamic HTML Select with unknown id and common class

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic, html-select

currently i have a form with dynamically generated select input.

Field name is an array in the form `name="myfield[]"` and they have a common class, example: `class="unknownfield"`

How can i, using Javascript or jQuery validate that every select on the Form has a selected which is not the default empty?

Comment: Using a `for...each` loop? http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to the extent of:

```
$("form select").each(function() {
    if (this.value == "") //empty!

});
```

Comment: Good aproach, but i need it based on class since i have other selects on the form that should not be touched, so can i change `$( "form select" )` for `$( ".myclass" )` .... ?

Comment: It works fine, seriously such a simple solution and i was stuck thinking in a complex one, thanks for your help.